# How to pass checkbox values to view

Tags: python, django, checkbox, django-templates, django-views

I'm coding a project to learn django. I have one checkbox that needs to change a value from the model. I'll try to summarize how my project is

```
# Model
class Model(models.Model):
  is_confirm = models.BooleanField(default=True)

# template
<div>
   <input type="checkbox" id="confirm" checked="{{ model.is_confirm }}">
</div>

<button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#updating" style="width:100%">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>Save
</button>

<div class="modal-header">
    <form action="{ url 'confim_view' model.id" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Update">Confirm</button>
    </form>                                         
</div>
```

Basically, I have the checkbox and I want update its value when a click the button save, a modal is open and when I click in Confirm button the value on database is changed. Actually, I can't get the value of the checkbox and send it to view via POST method. Does anyone have any idea how I can make this work?

Obs: The view to save is other than the view to show the object itself

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to to this:

`template.html`:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="confirm" {% if model_is_confirm %} checked="checked" {% endif %}>
```

`view.py`:

```
obj = Obj.objects.get(id=obj_id)
return render(request, 'template.html', {'model_is_confirm': obj.is_confirm})
```

Comment: Not all, I just wanna change the value  of is_confirm to false/true when de user check/uncheck the checkbox and click in save button. My problem is how to get this value and pass it to view. Like  the default value is true, when the user uncheck the checkbox the value the value needs to be update in the database to false. Set  self.is_confirm = False  in view and save it

Comment: I see. Then you just simply process the form in your view and update the model. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#the-view and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#updating-attributes-based-on-existing-fields